# Is it private pool mining efficient?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory, mining-hardware

I have several machines ready to mine. Is it more efficient to setup one machine as the central "pool"(e.g. with a software like [this](https://github.com/sammy007/monero-stratum)) and connect other machines/miners to it or is it more efficient to "solo" mine on each machine without a central pool. I'm aware of the pro/cons of public pools but I'm not interested(due the lack of trust).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private pool pros:

- You need only **1** copy of the blockchain and one node instance versus **n** copies for independent solo mining on each machine. You can help bandwidth by hooking 1 node to the outside network, and rest of them to this one "main" but you'd still have **n** copies of the blockchain on each machine.
- You have more versatility with regards to mining software as some of them work only with pools
- You can set worker IDs and monitor each miner stats from one single place

Private pool cons:

- Involves more time to learn how to set up and maintain a private pool.

There shouldn't be any measurable performance differences, and you could even set up each machine to solo-mine to the pool but you get the benefits of optimizing your network / storage requirements.

Also, you might want to consider [this pool software](https://github.com/Snipa22/nodejs-pool) as well. For that one, if you get stuck with it I believe you could find help rather quick in #monero-pools channel on IRC

Comment: Wouldn't the latency between the miner and the pool have a slight affect?

Comment: Yeah, but I believe that on the same network it's insignificant if you set the share difficulty right, like every 30s. Then you lose some miliseconds for each 30s.

Comment: Also, you can set each worker to solo-mine to the pool :)

Comment: I guess that could add up but would running monerod affect the hashrate? so if storage is not an issue would it be better to solo mine? Edit: missed the second comment.

Comment: So it is better to have higher share difficulty and submit to the pool only every 30s as opposed to for example every 5s? The miner has to pause mining while waiting for the pool to accept the share?

Comment: Some pools auto-adjust difficulty. I'm not familiar with intricate details, but you can always experiment to find the sweet spot. There shouldn't be any waiting for share acceptance, but there could be some delay in waiting for new work. This way, each small network delay would shave some time off your productive time. The less of them, the better.